# Displacement vector tangent to ambient space or manifold

Tags: multivariable-calculus

When addressing the difference between single and multivariable integration, [Terence Tao mentions](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/forms.pdf):

> It turns out that there will be two dimensions which will be relevant: the dimension $n$ of the ambient space $\mathbf R^n,$ and the dimension $k$ of the path, oriented surface, or oriented manifold $S$ that one will be integrating over.
>
> ...
>
> The displacement $\Delta x_i:= x_{i+1} − x_i \in \mathbf R^n$
>   from $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$ is now a vector rather than a
>   scalar. (Indeed, one should think of $\Delta x_i$ as an infinitesimal *tangent vector* to the ambient space $\mathbf R^n$ at the point $x_i.$)

The question is whether the vector is supposed to be tangential to the ambient space, or rather to the manifold $S$ (embedded in an ambient space) at a  point $x_i$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your quote:

> Indeed, one should think of $Δx_i$ as an infinitesimal tangent vector to the ambient space $\mathbb R^n$ at the point $x_i$.

To see why this comment is relevant to your question, suppose that the ambient space is now the unit sphere $\mathbb S^2$ embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ and that your submanifold $S$ is the circular arc $\gamma$ parametrized by $(\cos t, \sin t, 0)$ for $t \in (0,\pi)$. Partition the arc into two smaller arcs, setting $t_0 = 0$, $t_1 = \pi/2$, and $t_2 = \pi$. Then the vector $\gamma(t_1) - \gamma(t_0)$ is $(-\sqrt 2/2,\sqrt 2 / 2)$, which is tangent to neither $\mathbb S^2$ nor the arc $\gamma(0,\pi)$. However, if we partition the arc even further, allowing the mesh size $|t_{i+1}-t_i|$ to go to zero, we see that, by approximating $\gamma$ to first order,
$$\begin{split}
\gamma(\tau) &= \gamma(0) + \gamma'(0)\cdot \tau + \mathtt o (\tau)
\end{split}$$
as $\tau \to 0$, that is
$$\frac{\gamma(\tau) - \gamma(0)}{\tau-0} \xrightarrow{\tau \to 0}\gamma'(0) = (0,1,0)  $$
which is a vector pointing in the $y$-direction. If you imagine this vector anchored at the point $\gamma(0) = (1,0,0)$, you see that it is tangent to both $\mathbb S^2$ and the path $\gamma(0,\pi)$.

You may try the same procedure around $\pi/2$ instead of $0$ to see that you could approach $\gamma(\pi/2)$ from both sides (something you cannot do at $0$ or $\pi$ because the path ends there), or try a completely different path in $\mathbb S^2$. The vectors you'll find will always be tangent to both the path and the ambient space $\mathbb S^2$.

Beware, however: if a vector is tangent to the submanifold $S$ of the ambient space, it will surely be tangent to the ambient space too. The converse is *not* true. Think the vector $(0,0,1)$ anchored at $\gamma(\pi/2)$: it is surely tangent to $\mathbb S^2$, but orthogonal to every vector tangent to $\gamma$ at $t = \pi/2$.

Comment: That is great - my mental construct just got increased by 1 element. The way I pictured was with $\mathbb R^3$ as the "ambient" space - the all encompassing Euclidean "universe." Now, in your explanation, this ambient space has shrunken to what I was picturing to be the manifold, and the parametrized line of integration made its appearance as the submanifold. It all make sense after $\mathbb R^3$ went away... Is there a name for $\mathbb R^3$ in this Russian doll construct?

Comment: If there is one, I don’t know it. I guess you could define a chain of embeddings or immersions to be a sequence of maps $M_1 \to M_2 \to \cdots \to M_p$ such that the composition of any two subsequent maps is again an embedding or immersion. In this case $M_n$ would probably be called “terminal element” of the sequence.